# How to add Icons in Commit Editing Style.

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to figure out how to add icons when swipping on a table View Cell the same way the mail app does it using the Commit Editing style. Any thoughts or ideas are greatly appreciated. :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many examples avaialble on Github. Some of them are as below.

1. [YMSwipeTableViewCell](https://github.com/yammer/YMSwipeTableViewCell)
2. [SESlideTableViewCell](https://github.com/spaceelephant/SESlideTableViewCell)
3. [AFMSlidingCell](https://github.com/ask-fm/AFMSlidingCell)
4. [MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell)
5. [JASwipeCell](https://github.com/joseria/JASwipeCell)
6. [SWRevealTableViewCell](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealTableViewCell)
7. [DNSSwipeableTableCell](https://github.com/designatednerd/DNSSwipeableTableCell)

You may use any of above as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no way you can achieve this functionality without third party frameworks.

I'm not an insider, but it is very likely that Apple will provide an API for that in the future.

Please see Rahul Patel's answer for Frameworks to use.